# Getopt error: memory protection violation

Tags: c, linux, getopt

I try to use `getopt`, but I have a problem.
After running `./a.out -A -R`, I see
`memory protection violation`.
What am I doing wrong?

```
int c;
int rec_flag=0;
int copy_range=0;
while((c=getopt(argc,argv,"AR:"))!=-1){
    switch(c){
        case 'A':
            copy_range=1;
            break;
        case 'R':
            rec_flag=1;
            break;
        case '?':
            if (optopt == 'c')
                fprintf (stderr, "Option -%c requires an argument.\n", optopt);
            else if (isprint (optopt))
                fprintf (stderr, "Unknown option `-%c'.\n", optopt);
            else
                fprintf (stderr,"Unknown option character `\\x%x'.\n",optopt);
            return 1;
        default:
            abort ();
    }
}
```

Comment: this isn't a [mcve]. Have you tried to run the code through a debugger?

Comment: my program needs 2 parameters(path to directory) and optional options like -A. i try "./a.out /home /bin -A" and this dont work

Comment: The issue is in `getopt` format string:

    `c=getopt(argc,argv,"AR:")`

the `:` means that `R` option expects an argument. You're not providing any. That should not crash as number of arguments passed is correct.

Comment: You're throwing away the value in `optarg` when the `-R name` option is recognized.  Either drop the colon after `R` from the string `"AR:"`, or stash the value of `optarg` somewhere to hold the name that's provided.  Are you sure the crash is in `getopt()` and not in some subsequent code?  Standard versions of `getopt()` should not crash just because the command is invoked incorrectly without an argument for the colon to match.

Comment: I am guessing that whatever function this is that is handling arguments, you are passing the arguments to the function wrong. Usually, the `getopt` code is handled in `main` directly, and the system would not pass arguments in incorrectly. However, if you specify a larger `argc` than what `argv` actually holds, you can encounter a runtime error.

Answer (score 0):

```c
while((c=getopt(argc,argv,"AR:"))!=-1){
 switch(c){
    ...
    case '?':  if (optopt == 'c')
                   fprintf (stderr, "Option -%c requires an argument.\n", optopt);
```

`getopt` will not set `optopt` to 'c' in your program ever.

In the example code you pasted this from, the format string was "abc:".  So `optopt` would be 'c' if `-c` was passed without an argument (which, as noted above, the colon in the format string means it requires).  Your program does not have an option `-c` at all.
You didn't remove the third option spec because your program accepts 2 arguments... right?

Make sure you #included `<unistd.h>` and `<ctype.h>` like it says, then try declaring the getopt variables as `extern`.  `Memory protection violation` might mean the linker is currently pulling them in as transitive includes, but the kernel doesn't expect your process to be accessing the shared memory region that part of libc is mapped to.  Just a guess, but it did clear up some misbehavior I experienced while trying to run your code.

https://www.gnu.org/software/libc/manual/html_node/Using-Getopt.html#Using-Getopt
https://www.gnu.org/software/libc/manual/html_node/Example-of-Getopt.html#Example-of-Getopt